# monetdblite: Is it possible to configure "monetdb_query" to run multiple statements?

Tags: sql, monetdblite

I am trying to run the following script

```
"create table T1(i int); create table T2(i int);"
```

in a fresh new database using MonetDBLite C and its "monetdb_query" API, but "monetdb_query" function seems to execute only first statement.

Is it any way I can run the whole script (dot-comma separated valid statements) at once (ideally in the same transaction)?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know, sorry. Happy to review a PR though. Main problem is that multiple queries might produce multiple result sets, which would greatly complicate the API. But if all you're after is the execution and you don't care about the result this can be done with some minor hacking. Try calling `monetdb_query_internal` with a lowercase 's' as last parameter.

Comment: It seems is not allowed. sql_upgrades.c, line 1098

`if (be->language !='S') {
  msg = createException(SQL, "SQLparser", SQLSTATE(42000) "Unrecognized language prefix: %ci\n", be->language);
  goto finalize;
 }`

and even after I changed the code to pass that condition for 's' as well, still did not work. I guess above condition was there for a reason.

Comment: The error message `Unrecognized language prefix: Li` can also be a symptom of the database being still in maintenance mode. To fix this, run `monetdb release <DATABASE_NAME>` followed by `monetdb start <DATABASE_NAME>`.